# Problem with appending model after previous linking

Tags: linked-data, append

Just starting to add external models to my scenes. I first tried linking a model but found that it wasn't really suitable for what I wanted since I couldn't apply changes or edit the model. I deleted the object from my scene and appended instead but still couldn't apply or edit. I tried with an older version of my scene by appending and I am able to apply and edit with no issue so it seems that somehow linking first has left something lying around that is causing me problems. I tried making everything local and that didn't help. Is there any way to see or "cleanup" these items that might be causing me trouble? (Or is it perhaps something else?)

Answer (score 0):

Well, putting it into words helped me look for the answer. In the outliner, there's a drop down which lists orphaned data. I cleaned that out and then I was good to go. There's also a clean up->purge option in the file menu but I never got to try that.